# Show scoreboard points with right clicking an item

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I have several scoreboards in an adventure map, so they can't all be shown in screen, and I want one particular scoreboard value to be shown in the chat when right clicking an item. For example, if I right click with a Gold Ingot it will say in the chat how many money I have. Is that possible?

Comment: I've done this before by detecting when the player opened the trade UI with a villager, but I'm not sure how to make it work with multiplayer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sorry, i just created this account so i can't comment on the previous answer.
https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria

What you need is the **stat.useItem.minecraft.*ItemName***. However, before using this criteria, please **READ** the description first (*Use is defined as when...*).
For the previous answer, there is no way to *use* gold ingot(right-clicking is **not** use, according to the definition), you should use some items that can be really *used*.
For example, *carrot on a sticks*, which you can actually use.

If you want to use an item that cannot be *used*, maybe you should consider detecting the player's click on an entity, such as **Villager**. However, this approach will **block** the player's interaction to other blocks/entities etc. So this approach should only be used in a fixed position(the player go to that position and click), or when the player won't try to interact with other entities/blocks. (the stat is stat.talkedToVillager, and the NBT tag that used to disable the GUI that would open when the player click the villager is... i forgot, but you can just google for it :P)

Answer (score 0):

You can't `testfor` if someone is right-clicking a gold ingot. The command would be:

```
/scoreboard objectives add [Name] stat.useItem.minecraft.gold_ingot
```

The command wouldn't `testfor` if someone right-clicked a gold ingot. You can find all of the things that can be used [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Scoreboard#Criteria).

It is possible to write a specific player's score for a specific objective, using:

```
/tellraw PLAYER {"score":{"name":"PLAYER","objective":"OBJECTIVE"}}
```

You need to change the first `PLAYER` to the player you want to get the message. The next `PLAYER` is the player whose score you want to show in the message.